# Trying to get child element using GetElement(SeachCriteria) but fails on Win10

Tags: c#, windows-10, wpf-controls, ui-automation, white-framework

We have a WPF project that we are migrating to Windows 10. We have automation tests for our application, which are written in TestStack.White.

We are facing a problem where random test cases fail while doing this operation:  `GetElement(SearchCriteria.ByautomationID("Automation ID"))`. There are no testcases which always fail but some test case always fail with the same problem.

It throws this exception:

```
Error occured while geting
ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,ControlType=pane,AutomationId="Some Value"
```

On Windows 7 these test cases are much more stable but on Windows 10, this issue pops up every time for a few test cases.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Any answers?? Still waiting!!! :(